# How to mock multiple functions in python?

Tags: python

I am new to unit testing and mocking in python, in below scenario I know how to mock the `get_name()` which doesn't have any parameter [mock example](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/python_mock_gotchas/), but I am not able to mock the below scenario which take `age` as an argument. Could you please help me to fix mock `test_name` function below?

```
# data_source.py
def get_name(a):
    return "Alice"+str(a)

def get_age():
    return 30
```

The Person class exposes a method that fetches data from the data source:

```
# person.py
from data_source import get_name

class Person(object):
    def name(self):
        age = get_age()
        return get_name(age)    

from mock import patch
from person import Person

@patch('person.get_name')
def test_name(mock_get_name):
    mock_get_name.return_value = "Bob"
    person = Person()
    name = person.name()
    assert name == "Bob"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What issue you are encountering? The `Mock` object swallow any arguments it is called with, unless `spec`ced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, apart from importing `get_name`, you also need to import `get_age`, since you use it in the Person class. Second, there is nothing like `person.get_name` defined ever. So you can't patch that. Instead, you probably wanted to patch `data_souce.get_name`.

But unfortunately, that doesn't work, because `data_source` is a python module, and `get_name` is a method within it that you want to redefine. The patch decorator would be good if `get_name` were a method within a `DataSource` class, for example. I don't know the exact reason why it doesn't work, because I did not take a deep dive into the implemenation details of the mock library, but the intention of the library is different than how you want to use it.

To solve the problem, you can eiter turn data_source into a class, or you can temporarily change the meaning of the name `get_name`, by assigning a different function or a lambda to it:

```
import data_source

def test_person():
    # replace the function
    data_source._real_get_name = data_source.get_name
    data_source.get_name=lamba a: "Bob"
    # do some work
    person = Person()
    name = person.name()
    # after use of the get_name function, put the original function back
    data_source.get_name=data_source._real_get_name
    # assert post condition
    assert name=="Bob"
```

Of course, changing what functions do severely affects your program and should be done with care, probably only for testing. Make sure you always put the original function back, even if an error is thrown unexpectedly.